# Was Phasma supposed to play a bigger part in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I've only seen The Force Awakens once, but I'm as far as I can remember, Phasma doesn't really do much, except:

> get taken hostage that one time and disable the shields around the Starkiller after being asked twice

Was she originally supposed to play a bigger role?

I was really expecting to see much more of her, or at least see her in combat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the contrary, she was supposed to play a *smaller* role - just being an incidental character - but was bumped up in importance.

According to [io9](http://io9.gizmodo.com/everything-thats-wrong-with-star-wars-the-force-awaken-1751756919):

> Captain Phasma, Finn’s commanding officer, was clearly meant to be a minor character who shows up in a couple of scenes and then Finn turns the tables on her in a funny moment before tossing her into a garbage compactor. And then they cast Gwendoline Christie in the role, and decided to upgrade her to major supporting character after all—Christie did a lot of press for this movie, remember.

Comment: Ah very interesting! Cheers

Comment: Well that certainly explains why her part in the film was so disposable.

Comment: I heard (forgot where though, sorry) that Phasma plays a major part in the new trilogy, and that it's just accidental that her screentime in VII is not bigger. And she will return in VIII. Also, the io9 quote, saying "clearly", smells like conjecture.

Comment: She returned, was basically incidental to the plot, then got thrown into a fire hole